# Disable Woocommerce product tags display by alphabetical order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, tags, template-tags

I have a Woocommerce e-shop where each product has at least five tags. The problem is each product's tags are displayed alphabetically on the single product page.

I would like to know if it's possible to display products tags without any sorting.

Supposing I entered the below tags in the following order:
`cTag, dTag, aTag, eTag, bTag`

**CURRENT** display:
`aTag, bTag, cTag, dTag, eTag`

**EXPECTED** display:
`cTag, dTag, aTag, eTag, bTag`

I tried to deal with the `single-product > meta.php` file to manage it, but I didn't find anything to deal with the `wc_get_product_tag_list` function.

Comment: did you ask on woo themes?

Answer (score 1):

wc_get_product_tag_list uses get_the_terms function, so you can use get_the_terms filter to reorder your tags:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'get_the_terms_filter', 10, 3 );
function get_the_terms_filter( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ){
  // filter...

  return $terms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the source of the issue:

The errors doesn't come from the display, but from the Wordpress post save/update.

How to reproduce:

1. Go to Post/Product tags:

[image]

2. Then, enter a new Tag:

[image]

3. Add it to the tag list:

[image]

As you can see, "Kiwi" is the latest added tag, and I want to display them as is.

4. Then save the post (product) changes:

[image]

As shown above, "Kiwi" isn't at the latest place anymore, it goes on the 4th place, and this isn't what I want.

To sum up, Wordpress is ordering alphabetically the different tags.

Can I tell Wordpress to let the order as the terms was entered ?